# Next.js + eslint: unable to resolve path to module 'fs/promises'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, eslintrc

I started a Next.js app and configured eslint.
My list of dev dependencies for it are:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0"
}
```

And my .eslintrc file is:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "airbnb",
        "airbnb/hooks",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:import/errors",
        "plugin:import/warnings",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 11,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "react-hooks"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [
                    ".js",
                    ".jsx"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "react/display-name": 1,
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off"
    }
}
```

My Node version is the latest, 15.11 (I'm on MacOS, if it matters).

The issue is that I'm importing:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';
```

And eslint throws

```
Unable to resolve path to module 'fs/promises'.
```

Otherwise, the script works, but I don't understand what's triggering the error.

Could anyone help?

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
yarn add -D eslint babel-eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier
```

`.eslintrc` file: (as above in the body of my question)

`file-example.js`:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs/promises'; // <= this throws "Unable to resolve path to module 'fs/promises'.

function HomePage(props) {
  const { products } = props;
  return (
    <ul>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <li key={product.id}>{product.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'data', 'dummy-backend.json');
  const jsonData = await fs.readFile(filePath);
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  return {
    props: {
      products: data.products,
    },
  };
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Strange. If you haven't already, I'd try reinstalling the `node_modules` folder (delete it if it's already present). Alternatively, you can try `import { promises } from "fs";` and see if that works. On that note, I'm on node `v14.16.0` and it appears to be importing properly using both methods.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tried reinstalling the modules (both with yarn and with npm) but the error persists. `import {promises} from 'fs'` doesn't work at all and breaks the app, I'm afraid...

Comment: v.14.4 produces the same error. I just updated my question with an mcve, hope it helps!

Comment: Ahh, it's being used in `getStaticProps`. Take a look at this NextJS [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7755) and this NextJS [discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12124)

Comment: So, for what I quickly understood, I have to add an eslint rule to turn the warning off and live with it? I mean, the file works just fine, but it flags it as an error. I'm sorry I'm not entirely sure about what to do as I'm pretty new to Next. I appreciate your links a lot! By the way, the error is there even without `getStaticProps`. It just appears as soon as I import fs.

Comment: For extra context, I created the app with `npx create-next-app`. I wonder if this is webpack-related?

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue. This [example repo](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/getstaticprops-fs-example) works as [expected](https://i.imgur.com/4vDpMgV.png)

Comment: Hey Matt, really appreciate your time! Well, I cloned your repo and still have exactly the same issue. The only difference is that I have to add `babel-eslint` as a dependency because that's the one declared as parser in .eslintrc. In case I didn't mention it before, I use VSCode with the eslint extension which ultimately is the one flagging the error.

Comment: Since its just related to the eslint extension and doesn't impact compilation, I'd recommend filing an issue with them. As is, running `eslint` or (`yarn lint` from my example repo) doesn't display any issues.

Comment: I just did, Matt. Thank you very much for your interest and time! The issue still puzzles me!

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta you you have a lint to that issue? I suffer the same problem, also tried many things without any success.

Comment: "have you a link?" I wanted to say ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Though I was not using react, but pure typescript, I experienced an same issue. I resolved it by configuring like the example below, with [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript).

```js
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        alwaysTryTypes: true
      },
    },
  }
```

`alwaysTryTypes: true` made it works, as it lets eslint respect `node_modules/@types/*`, which includes `@types/node`, which contains `"fs/promises"` declaration (in case of recent version).